# D-Bus Remote Controlled Car Example

Tags: c++, qt

I try to send integer value from one to another programme using for IPC QtDBUS(they are different executable files). My attempts to find simple example was unsuccessful. So, I am forced to build huge example D-Bus Remote Controlled Car Example like for one who has never used QtDBus. I repeated full tree structure(sources, headers). But one file controller.h includes #include “ui_controller.h”. There is no such file. So, I am not able to compile.
Maybe, is there something that I don’t understand?

http://s016.radikal.ru/i336/1112/ad/d4f681cbc2cd.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ui_* files are generated in the build process. You can find the complete sources of all the dbus examples, including the one you're referring to [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/master/examples/dbus).